# C#: SQL can't execute the reading

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've ordered SQL Server from Somee. I want to use this SQL Server for my windows form. Somehow, i'm not sure, but whenever i execute the login query what i've found, it will have an unhandled exeption.

```
        private void log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "workstation id=wbhandler.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=acc;pwd=pw;data source=wbhandler.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=wbhandler";
        con.Open();

        string felh = username.Text;
        string jelsz = password.Text;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account=@felhasznalo AND password=@jelszó";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@felhasznalo", felh));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@jelszó", jelsz));
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows == true ) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Succes");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        }
    }
```

I thought that the adress is wrong, but then i found on the website the connection string, and now i don't really know.

I'm thinking what's the problem is.
I have 3 schemes in the sql:
dbo, acc, guest.

I first created a table in dbo, then in acc. Now in both of it. But it doesn't execute the  `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`, sadly. Like i said, it has unhandled exeption. Any solution? Any ideas?

(the acc scheme is an example what i created in somee, so it doesn't exist, it's fake)

I also tried this way:

```
 using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sikeres Login!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sikertelen Login");
                }
            }
```

The problem is always the `ExecuteReader()`

Comment: What is in the unhandled exception (InnerException)?

Comment: You really should be using `using` statmens around all the objects that implement `.Dispose()` otherwise your connections are not going to be closed. Also please click the ["Copy Expecption Detail to Clipboard"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) link in visual studio and paste the text it gives you [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22271581/edit) (be sure to "code format it" by highlighting the text and clicking the `{ }` icon after you paste)

Comment: I've used try/catch, and it catched.

Exeption: SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); This line has error

Unhandled Exeption: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: Check if the innerexception property of the exception caught by your catch contains more informations

Comment: Did switching to `AddWithValue` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@felhasznalo", felh);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jelszó", jelsz);
```

I will also recommend that you use `using` statements on your `SQL` objects to ensure that the unmanaged resources they consume are freed when they are no longer needed. You can read more on the `using` statement from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Another thing that I can suggest is adding `Charset=utf8;` to your connection string.